# Diagrams in PhpStorm don't work

Tags: uml, phpstorm

I just imported a PHP project into PhpStorm for the first time, and now I want PhpStorm to show me the UML diagram of the project. The online documentation says I should select 'Diagrams' in the context menu of a file, but there is no such item. Alternatively, I should be able to use Ctrl + Shift + Alt + U to display the diagram - nothing happens. By searching everything with Ctrl + Shift + A after 'diagram' I get the option "Show UML diagram", but when i click it, nothing happens. The UML Support plugin is installed and enabled.

If that matters, I'm currently using the free trial to decide whether or not I should use PhpStorm in my PHP-Projects. However, this shouldn't be a concern because as far as I know it *should* provide access to all features.

Comment: Whats your PHP Storm version? I'm using the 2016.2.2 and the diagrams render normally. You should right click the file in the project explorer, the "Diagrams" option doesn't appear through right click in the tab bar file.

Comment: 2016.2 x64... I did rightclick it in the explorer - Although I just noticed that it does work with files which contain only a class, but nothing else

Comment: In that case I suggest that you contact their customer support.